# SoapUI Mock Service Missing operation error

Tags: soapui, weblogic12c

I want to mock a Webservice for development environment.
I have *SOAPUI version 5.2.1* and the following *WSDL*:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
xmlns:tns="http://server.com/SSO" 
targetNamespace="http://server.com/SSO">
    <wsdl:documentation>Web service</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://server.com/SSO">
            <s:element name="GetProfile2">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Token" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SiteName" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TimeStamp" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EncodedPwd" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EncodedType" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Filter" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="GetProfile2Response">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GetProfile2Result" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="GetCache">
                <s:complexType/>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="GetCacheResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GetCacheResult" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetProfile2SoapOut">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:GetProfile2Response" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>  
    <wsdl:message name="GetProfile2SoapIn">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:GetProfile2" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServiceSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetProfile2">
            <wsdl:documentation>Returns a user</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetProfile2SoapIn">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetProfile2SoapOut">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCache">
            <wsdl:documentation>Returns the cached abilitations.</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCacheSoapIn">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCacheSoapOut">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoap" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetProfile2">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://server.com/SSO/GetProfile2" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetCache">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://server.com/SSO/GetCache" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding> 
    <wsdl:service name="Service">
        <wsdl:documentation>Web service</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://server.com:7001/services/Service.ServiceSoap/"/>
        </wsdl:port>   
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I've created in *SOAPUI* a new soap project, with mock service, I've set the host and the port of the *Weblogic server 12c* where I have to install the war.

In *SOAPUI* preferences I have unchecked Logs wire content of all...", in MockService Properties I have set "Require SAOP Action" to false, and I've export as WAR the project and install into *Weblogic 12c*.

Ok, the problem is that, the first call to the webservice is ok, and I get the expected response.

From the second call I get the following error:

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Missing operation for soapAction [http://server.com/SSO/GetProfile2] and body element [{http://server.com/SSO}GetProfile2] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapUtils.findOperationForRequest(SoapUtils.java:330)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:191)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:113)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet$MockServletSoapUICore.dispatchRequest(MockAsWarServlet.java:247)
at com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet.service(MockAsWarServlet.java:182)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

If i remove the message tags from wsdl everything is ok. Help me Please!!!

Comment: what is the name of the war file ? is it same as name of the mock service name? and what is the size of the war file that gets generated?

Comment: one thing I know is that war generated can be deployable under tomcat. Not sure about other AppServers.

Comment: Would you mind to update the question with details of - how mock dispatcher is implemented?

Comment: Mr. Rao I have implemented using Random dispatcher. Till the deployment and first request fired , I have attached the log in this question.

Comment: I suspect ..please Look at this .. https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/R-Missing-operation-for-soapAction-and-body-element-moc/m-p/38006#M15297

Comment: I suspect also... but i don't understand how change the wsdl. Rao i use default value for dispatch SEQUENCE

Comment: then the solution should be, remove the message from wsdl? I nedd to mock a wsdl with messagge, with soapui is impossible!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to weblogic 12.c

1. My Soapui Project from the above wsdl , I have created mock that responds randomly and mock properties

[image]

Mock Properties:
[image]

2. Mock Service in soapui below is the pic, all operations uses random mock response

> Note: Export project as war from soapui, I have taken care context and
>   war name as same

[image]

3. Login to weblogic--> deployments --> install and point the war file that got from soapui.

[image]

4. I have provided context name as "mocksoap"

[image]

5. Select option Yes, take me to the deployments configuration screen and click finish
   [image]
6. Select -->control tab--> select the context and click start and all services

[image]

7. Cross check under monitoring -->Servlets it should list all the servlets got deployed
    [image]
8. Access the Servelet and select WSDL to be tested

[image]
 9. Open the soapui and Test the mock service war you deployed to weblogic and it will behave as a brand new testable service.
    I have shown below how i got random responses, Also Notice its pointing to my weblogic endpoint

[image]

If you like the answer please don forgot to vote!!!

Comment: I have followed your instruction, i have understood the problem is in WSDL. Because, if you try to test GetProfile2, instead of GetCache, you get the error.

Comment: Also If you look at soapui.log under your domain folder i see this error message. 2016-05-31 08:34:03,683 WARN  [SchemaUtils] Error: zip:/scratch/sgongali/gitlocal/soa-apiplatform/out/domains/drt/servers/api/tmp/_WL_user/mocksoap/ajtj4k/war/WEB-INF/lib/soapui-5.2.1.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/soapEncoding.xsd:0: warning: id-idref-idrefs-entity-entities-notation: For compatibility, type 'ENTITY' should only be used for attributes (used for element 'ENTITY@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/').

Comment: Also Would you please answer to Mr.RAO

Comment: Inside soapui the problem is resolved unchecked "Enable Mock Http Log".
The problem is present inside weblogic :(

Comment: I also tried on a weblogic 12.2.  It's working fine but ... only once !!.  The first try with soapui gives me a response.  For all the next one I've got (in weblogic) <May 25, 2018, 11:02:36,175 AM CEST> <Error> <com.eviware.soapui.mockaswar.MockAsWarServlet> <BEA-000000> <null
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Missing operation for soapAction [] and body element ...  If I redeploy, it's working again once.  I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error with soapUI, with response coming 1st time and then for subsequent request it was getting blank. It seems like library issue. Use https://github.com/eveoh/weblogic-soapui-mock-ear to wrap the war into ear. This has resolved issue for me. I have used weblogic 12c, soap UI 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in SoapUI 5.7.0. I had to start the SoapUI app as the root user in Linux. Then all worked fine.

Ref: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/Sometimes-quot-Missing-operation-for-soapAction-quot/m-p/139066/highlight/true#M10131